# Is there anyway to determine the height of a string of HTML without using a UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios

I want to know the size of a piece of HTML, but I don't want to use a `UIWebView`.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: It could be anything. I'm creating a inbox controller for a messaging system, and we allow messages to have HTML. There could be lists, links, headers, etc.